# newbie Django Choicefield/Charfield display on html page

Tags: python, html, django, forms, return

I have been reading the django book and the django documentation, but still can figure it out.

i have this `model.py`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Zonas(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class ZonasForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Zonas
```

this `view.py`:

```
from django    import forms
from testApp.models import Zonas
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def menuForm (request):
    z = list (Zonas.objects.all())
    numbers = forms.CharField(max_length=30,
            widget=forms.Select(choices=z))

    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'numbers':numbers})
```

this `html`:

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="get">
    <div class="field">

{{ form.numbers }}

</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Ans this `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from testApp.views import menuForm

urlpatterns = patterns('',

   url(r'^hello/$',  menuForm ),
)
```

All i get when i run the server is a page only with the submit button, and no form.number wich is supossed to be a select menu.
I tried this `views.py`:

```
def menuForm (request):
    z = list (Zonas.objects.all())
    numbers = forms.ChoiceField(choices=z)
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'numbers':numbers})
```

But the result is the same...

Any hints? Should i use a diferent return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access `{{ form.numbers }}` when you never pass a `form` variable to the template. You would need to access `numbers` directly with `{{ numbers }}`.

Also you aren't quite using forms correctly. Check this out https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Create a menu form that contains a [ModelChoiceField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField)

#### forms.py

```
class MenuForm(Form):
    zonas = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Zonas.objects.all())
```

Now [use that form in your view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view)

#### views.py

```
from myapp.forms import MenuForm

def menuForm(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = MenuForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
        if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
            # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
            # ...
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/') # Redirect after POST

    else:
        form = MenuForm() # An unbound form

    return render(request, 'hello.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Now you can [use the form in your template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template)

#### hello.html

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `ModelChoiceField`? This code works for me.

views.py:

```
from django import forms
from models import Zonas
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response


class NumbersForm(forms.Form):
    numbers = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Zonas.objects.all())


def menuForm(request):
    form = NumbersForm()
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'form': form})
```

hello.html:

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <div class="field">

        {{ form.as_p }}

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as_p redirects to numbersform()?

Comment: it's designed for displaying the form in the template, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#displaying-a-form-using-a-template. Hope that helps.

Comment: the as_p method returns the string needed render the form in html.

Answer (score 1):

You have several errors in your applications. Let's do the following:

You will need the following files in your `testApp` folder: `models.py`, `views.py`, `forms.py`. Now, inside `models.py` you will define model `Zonas` (pretty much as you have done)

```
#models.py
from django.db import models

class Zonas(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, inside the `forms.py` file you will have this:

```
from testApp.models import Zonas
from django.forms import ModelForm

z = ((zona.name,zona.name) for zona in Zonas.objects.all())

class ZonasForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=30,widget=forms.Select(choices=z))
    class Meta:
        model = Zonas
```

Then, your `views.py`:

```
from testApp.forms import ZonasForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def menuForm (request):
    if request.method = 'POST':
        form = ZonasForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = ZonasForm()
    return render_to_response('hello.html', {'form':form})
```

There you have your form processed and everything.

Next, your `hello.html`:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="field">

         {{ form.as_p }}

    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

All of this combined should work. You had some concept errors in your app definition, I hope this could help as a guide.